# Customizing the country plugin created by javascript with that i am trying adding sum few functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently customizing the javascript countries plugin with jquery with the current code where I can able to show the default country value as United Arab Emirates but the state was not viewing for the default value. I am was not able go further where getting confused.

here is the current jquery code where I am customizing the drop down value as UAE

```
$('.ipt_Country').val('United Arab Emirates').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/eRv2W/846/)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your document ready part to this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    populateCountries("country", "state"); 
    $('.ipt_Country').val('United Arab Emirates').attr("selected", "selected"); 

    populateStates('country','state'); 
});
```

Comment: very simple i was not getting :)